# How can I mass remove a single number in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, google-sheets-formula, find-replace

I have a Google Sheet with over 30,000 rows. I would like to remove the 0 from all the cells that contain a single 0, but keep the cells that have numbers like 50, 120 etc.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Would you be interested in a Google Apps Script solution?

Answer (score 0):

press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd>

type in:

```
^0$
```

and hit **Replace all**:

[image: 0]